# Query to get the customers active in Aug month and inactive in Sep month in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Please help me to find the customers who were active in the month of aug 15 (in terms of transaction ) and inactive in SEP 15.

The query is taking more than 45 min ..Kindly help ..

```
    SELECT DISTINCT C.CustomerCode--,x.CustomerCode
    FROM Customer.Customer(nolock) c
    INNER JOIN Customer.Card (nolock)cd ON c.CustomerId=cd.CustomerId
    INNER JOIN Trans.vwValidRawTransactions  rt (nolock) ON rt.AccountNumber=cd.CardNumber AND rt.AccountTypeId=3
    where c.CustomerCode not in (
        SELECT DISTINCT ca.customercode
         FROM Customer.customer Ca (nolock)
         INNER JOIN Customer.Card cd (nolock) ON ca.CustomerId=cd.CustomerId
         INNER JOIN trans.vwValidRawTransactions ra (nolock) ON cd.CardNumber=ra.AccountNumber AND ra.AccountTypeId=3 AND ra.IsLive=1
         WHERE Ra.TransactionDate>='01-09-2015' AND Ra.TransactionDate <'01-10-2015'  ) 

 and  rt.TransactionDate>='01-08-2015' and rt.TransactionDate<'01-09-2015'
```

Comment: Without knowing the indexing or rowcounts it is difficult to recommend a solution.

Comment: Thanks..customer.customer table contains two columns customer code,customer id both are unique and indexing is on customer id..

Answer (score 0):

Try using `between`,

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.CustomerCode,
       x.CustomerCode
FROM   Customer.Customer(NOLOCK) c
       INNER JOIN Customer.Card (NOLOCK)cd
            ON  c.CustomerId = cd.CustomerId
       INNER JOIN Trans.vwValidRawTransactions rt(NOLOCK)
            ON  rt.AccountNumber = cd.CardNumber
            AND rt.AccountTypeId = 3
WHERE  c.CustomerCode NOT 
       IN (SELECT DISTINCT ca.customercode
           FROM   Customer.customer Ca(NOLOCK)
                  INNER JOIN Customer.Card cd(NOLOCK)
                       ON  ca.CustomerId = cd.CustomerId
                  INNER JOIN trans.vwValidRawTransactions ra(NOLOCK)
                       ON  cd.CardNumber = ra.AccountNumber
                       AND ra.AccountTypeId = 3
                       AND ra.IsLive = 1
           WHERE  Ra.TransactionDate BETWEEN '01-09-2015' AND '01-10-2015')
       AND rt.TransactionDate BETWEEN '01-08-2015' AND '01-09-2015'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear because your query is way more complicated than what the question asks.

If you are looking at the transaction table, you can do what you want using aggregation and a `having` clause:

```
SELECT rt.AccountNumber
FROM Trans.vwValidRawTransactions rt (nolock)
WHERE rt.AccountTypeId = 3 AND
      rt.TransactionDate >= '2015-08-01' AND
      rt.TransactionDate < '2015-10-01'
GROUP BY rt.AccountNumber
HAVING MONTH(MAX(rt.TransactionDate)) = 8;
```

That is, take transactions from the two months.  Then choose customers where the month of the maximum date is august.  These customers have transactions in August, but not September.

Note the use of ISO standard date formats.  You should use standard date formats in SQL code.

I'm not sure what the rest of your query is supposed to be doing.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion..Actually i need the result set which have those customer codes who have transacted in the month of Aug 15 but were inactive in the month of Sep 15..thats why i used that query..but that was taking much more time than expected...help needed..

Comment: customer.customer table contains two columns customer code,customer id both are unique and indexing is on customer id..

Comment: @AishwaryaMishra . . . This returns the `AccountNumber` that transacted in August but not in September.  However, you join to other tables is not really relevant to finding this information.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    SELECT DISTINCT C.CustomerCode--,x.CustomerCode
        FROM Customer.Customer(nolock) c
        INNER JOIN Customer.Card (nolock)cd ON c.CustomerId=cd.CustomerId
        INNER JOIN Trans.vwValidRawTransactions  rt (nolock) 
ON rt.AccountNumber=cd.CardNumber AND rt.AccountTypeId=3 AND 
    ((rt.IsLive =1 and rt.TransactionDate BETWEEN '01-08-2015' AND '01-09-2015')
 or (rt.IsLive !=1  and rt.TransactionDate BETWEEN '01-09-2015' AND '01-10-2015'))
```